# php unwritable for the file under /etc

Tags: php, linux

I want to write a script to config the centos network config file!But I had no permission to write these config files(/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0)!Even I gave the whole etc dir 777 permission.But it didn't work!

```
chmod -R 777 /etc
```

the php scirpt test file readable or writeable:

```
$file = "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0";
$link = fopen($file,"r+");
echo $file,is_readable($file)?"yes":"no<br>";
echo $file,is_writable($file)?"yes":"no<br>";
```

the result unreadable and unwritable:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0yes
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0no
```

Who can give me some suggesion!

Comment: You will need a root permission to change permission of such system directories. Otherwise anyone can write up some code and hack into anyone's system.

Comment: Could you create a subfolder of /etc and give ownership of it to the php user?

Comment: @Rikesh I login in as root!I give the permission of such directories as root,too!

Comment: Does the directory `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/` exist? Careful changing all of `/etc` to 777. You're just asking for problems.

Comment: I have to agree with @IanHunter. This is just asking for problems. If you need to control the behavior, don't change the permissions of the /etc directory. Look for a less direct way of affecting change. Otherwise you risk making your server inaccessible or open to hackers.

Comment: @lanHunter,yes,is not `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/`,is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`!But it still is unwritable?I had updated my code above!

Answer (score 0):

Your file information may be cached. Try running this script to get it to work. (See [the PHP documentation for more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).)

```
<?php clearstatcache(); ?>
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to tell us what the result of `stat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` is in your shell.

Never run `chmod -R 777 /etc`. At best, this may cause problems with programs expecting certain permissions. In the worst case scenario, your entire system could be compromised by a hacker, and it may already have been. Consider using a fresh installation of your operating system rather than continuing to use this server.